# How to calculate old date from today by subtracting given years, months, days in logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to subtract current date with given years, months, days using logstash pipeline.

For example : Today = 1 Aug 2021

Given values : Years=25, Months=10, Days=10

Expected date : 22 Sept 1995

My logstash filter section :

```
ruby {
        code => '
            years = 25
            months = 10
            days = 10
            datenow = Time.now.utc.to_date
            delUntilYear = datenow.year - "#{years}".to_i
            delUntilMonth = datenow.month - "#{months}".to_i
            delUntilDay = datenow.day - "#{days}".to_i
            event.set("[deleteTillDate]", "#{delUntilYear}-#{delUntilMonth}-#{delUntilDay} 00:00:00.000")
        '
    }
```

This is giving negative values for delUntilMonth and delUntilDay .
How to handle such situation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using DateTime

```
    ruby {
        code => '
            datenow = DateTime.now
            datenow = datenow.prev_year(25)
            datenow = datenow.prev_month(10)
            datenow = datenow.prev_day(10)
            event.set("[deleteTillDate]", datenow.to_date.to_s)
        '
    }
```

will produce

```
"deleteTillDate" => "1995-10-25",
```